# Send a file without using multipart

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I know how to send file using multipart but this time i'm using just a hashmap for sending a file but its not sending here is my code:

```
WebApi client = ServiceGenerator.createService(WebApi.class);
            UserInfoFieldsModel userInfoFieldsModel = new UserInfoFieldsModel();
            userInfoFieldsModel.file = view().returnFile();
            Map<String, Object> queries = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    //
            queries.put("first_name",  values.get(0));
            queries.put("middle_name",   "");
            queries.put("last_name",   values.get(1));
            queries.put("mobile_number",  values.get(3) );
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(ImageUtils.compressImage(
                    context, userInfoFieldsModel.file.getAbsolutePath(), "fitbook_image"));
            File file = new File(uri.getPath());
            queries.put("photo", file);
```

here is my web api:

```
 @PUT(CREATE_USER+"/{id}")
    Call<BaseResponse> updateUser(@Path("id") String id,
                                  @Body Map<String, Object> params);
```

Here are the fields that i'm going to send my data with, the back - end dev said that i should send it as file.

[image]

Comment: You have to convert the image into a string or any other format and pass with API params

Comment: Instead of sending the file into HashMap, send the Base64 string of the file into hash map and one important thing is, you should have to check what method used into the back-end.

Comment: but the back end send it should be in file format

Comment: say them we are sending as file(base64) they need to convert it just a single line code file_content(base64) something like this

Answer (score 0):

convert your photo or file to base64 and send that file..

```
 public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Log.d("encodedImage", "getStringImage: "+encodedImage);
        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
        Log.d("decodedByte", "getStringImage: "+decodedByte.toString());
        //sharedPrefManager.storeImage(encodedImage);
         bitmap.getAllocationByteCount();
        Log.d("bitmap_size", "getStringImage: "+bitmap.getAllocationByteCount());

        return encodedImage;

    }




  Uri uri = Crop.getOutput(result);
  bitmap =MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), uri);
  image = getStringImage(bitmap);
```

And say your back end team to convert that image to base64 and insert into database

Comment: @netflixspotify we can't send image as file based on that we can send image as base64 and backend team get base64 and convert and insert into table that's it